Перестал приходить authorization_code
Пытаюсь получить authorization_code через VK ID.
Отправляю GET-запрос в соответствии с документацией. Получаю обратно редирект, но с пустым device_id. Причем вчера все работало. Совершенно не понимаю как диагностировать проблему. Может быть превышен какой-то лимит на количество запросов access_token?
Запрос:
https://id.vk.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=55555555&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvideo.test.com%2FStoreAuthCode.php&state=0IeVPRMh...&code_challenge=Jb_ARvjo_...&code_challenge_method=s256

Ответ redirect:
https://id.vk.com/auth?app_id=55555555&client_id=55555555&device_id=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://video.test.com/StoreAuthCode.php&scope=&sdk_type=vkid&lang_id=0&scheme=&oauth_version=2&redirect_state=0IeVPRMh&code_challenge=Jb_ARvjo_...&code_challenge_method=sha256

То есть device_id пустой. В чем может быть дело? Помогите, пожалуйста!

В итоге заработало само собой. Видимо, действительно есть ограничение на количество запросов нового acces_token при уже существующем.
